# I want to display the records in a circular position using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I wants to display the records in a circular position using php.

It is coming from Mysql DB. It is dynamic records, It may be 10 or 2 or 3 or 8.

**For ex 1:**

```
       2      3

 1                  4

 8                  5

       7       6
```

**For ex 2:**

```
      2

 1         3

      4
```

**For ex 3:**

```
       2      3

 1                  4

    7            5

           6
```

How can I do this in PHP.

Comment: Try to explain a little more detailed what it is you want?  what kind of record? are it always the same number of records?

Comment: It is coming from Mysql DB. It is dynamic records, It may be 10 or 2 or 3 or 8.

Comment: @user2688251,It's representation of data so it's not possible with PHP,You can use jQuery,Javascript to represent in this manner.

Comment: You tagged it javascript.. do you accept a javascript solution?

Comment: Yes, But data must come from PHP, mysql DB

Comment: I have explained in details with examples. How can you say this is unclear? Provide me a solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some work to provide, you can adapt [the response made here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813573/position-icons-into-circle) by replacing the images by the numbers you got from PHP.

Comment: Here position is fixed. But I need this dynamic one. It may be 10 or 2 or 13 or 8 or 25 records.

Comment: Since you'll know the number returned by your query in PHP, you can make a list of the desired angles by dividing 360 by the number of records.