# How to rotate images in circular path like this in blogger dynamic view template

Tags: java, jquery, html, css

[image]

How to rotate images in circular path like this in blogger dynamic view template
and when i click any image in circular path  it should open the specified link

Comment: please write what have you tried so far.

Comment: i tried html css codes but it didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Position icons into circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813573/position-icons-into-circle)

Comment: will  this works in blogger (dynamic template)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what `blogger dynamic view template` is, but if you can write custom `CSS3` + `HTML` tags, the following code should suffice.

Screenshot first:
[image: spinning image with clickable parts]

What it does is basically rotating the image infinite times while make every circle icon of the image clickable.
:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @keyframes myfirst
        {
            from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
            to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
        }

        img {
            animation-name: myfirst;
            animation-duration: 5s;
            animation-timing-function: linear;
            animation-delay: 0s;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-direction: normal;
            animation-play-state: running;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <img src="pic.png" usemap ="#planetmap"/>
    <map name="planetmap">
      <area shape="circle" coords="67,95,40" href="example.com"/>
      <area shape="circle" coords="177,60,40" href="example.com"/>
      <area shape="circle" coords="244,150,40" href="example.com"/>
      <area shape="circle" coords="69,211,40" href="example.com"/>
      <area shape="circle" coords="180,247,40" href="example.com"/>
    </map>
</body>
</html>
```

*Special Note: Please go to MDN for compatibility information, as CSS3 has not stabilized.*