# How to create hexogon shaped / neural network of photos

Tags: css

I'm having a tough time properly describing what needs to be done to make the below happen in CSS. Is there an effective way to do this in CSS with images? If so what is the proper way to describe this shape / layout? If no example, how would you implement this? Should it just be a png?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look at:

- [Position icons into circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813573/position-icons-into-circle)
- http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/04/02/items-on-circle/
- http://www.connolly-technologies.com/jquery-arrange-items-in-a-circle/

You also use `transform: rotate(xxxdeg)` in css to distribute the images evenly around.